# about expectation of probability distributions

Tags: probability-theory

I have difficulty to solve E(Y) from Bernoulli distribution with parameter p which is P(X=1)=p=1-P(X=0), E(Y/X=0)=1 and   E(Y/X=1)=2 then what is E(Y) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

$$E[Y]= E[Y \mid X=0] P(X=0) + E[Y \mid X=1] P(X=1)$$